# Survival function

Tags: probability

Let $S_{0}(t) = (1-\frac{t}{105})^{1/5}$ be the survival function of a newborn. What is the median future lifetime at age $50$? So $$S_{50}(t) = \frac{S_{0}(50+t)}{S_{0}(50)} = \frac{\left(1-\frac{50+t}{105}\right)^{1/5}}{ \left(1-\frac{50}{105}\right)^{1/5}}$$

The median future lifetime would be the value of $s$ such that $$
\int_{0}^{s} \frac{\left(1-\frac{50+t}{105}\right)^{1/5}}{ \left(1-\frac{50}{105}\right)^{1/5}} \ dt = 0.5$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Are you looking for the _median_ or the _mean_?

Comment: @Sasha: Just by solving for it after doing the integration?

Comment: @Sasha: This would be correct for the probability density function, but not for the survival function.

Comment: @joriki Silly me. I have removed the incorrect comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you did would be correct if this were the probability density function for the time of death. However, the [survival function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) is a function specifying the probability that the newborn will still be alive at time $t$, which is the complement of the cumulative distribution function of the time of death. Then the median future lifetime at age $50$ is just the lifetime beyond $50$ at which half the people who were still alive at $50$ have died, that is,

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{50+t}{105}\right)^{1/5}
&=
\frac12\left(1-\frac{50}{105}\right)^{1/5}\;,
\\
1-\frac{50+t}{105}
&=
\frac1{32}\left(1-\frac{50}{105}\right)
\;,\\
55-t
&=
\frac{55}{32}
\;,\\
t
&=
53\frac9{32}\;.
\end{align}
$$

So the median corresponds to people who will live up to the age of $103\frac9{32}$, which seems rather unrealistic, but you can see from [a plot of the survival function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%281-t/105%29%5E%281/5%29%20for%20t=0..105) that this is about right.